# Off behaviour con promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm facing the following issue with a chain of promises

I have this chain of promises where I set a variable with what's going to be executed based on a data type

```
if (data.type === 'type1') {
       actionToExecute = action1;
       resultToExecute = result1;
       resultMsg = "result1";
   } else {
       actionToExecute = action2;
       resultToExecute = result2;
       resultMsg = "result2";
   }
   return actionToExecute(comment)
       .then(() => {
           return resultToExecute(data.id)
       })
       .then((response) => {
           ....
       }
```

In this scenario, `resultoToExecute` is `action1`

```
action1: (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      return api.fetchItems(id)
      .then((response) => {
        let action = {
          'id': id,
          'items': response
        }
        dispatch({
          type: 'UPDATE-ITEMS',
          action
        })
      })
```

But, on the response of the promise chain I'm getting instead of the execution of the arrown function, the function itself

[image: function response]

As, todo `response()` so the API call can be made and the reducer does what's expected to do.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note: Sorry if the code is vague, but I can't give much about as it's the client code

Edit1: And now, I feel stupid

Comment: I don't even see how you can call `.then`. `action1` returns a function when called, not a promise.

Comment: Indeed you are returning a function (that needs two arguments --- what were you intending to pass as values for them?)

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, I just saw what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

And I just realised my mistake, thanks to Felix Kling I just saw that, indeed, I'm not returning a promise, but a simple function